# Ordering in an SQL query

Tags: sql, count, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I have some data that includes the names of chess opening moves. I am trying to fond out which is the most common opening move for the white player.

I have been able to group the white player information (player_id, player_rating and opening_move) into a table, and then count the opening moves using the following:

```
SELECT opening_name, count(*)
FROM whiteopeningmove
GROUP BY opening_name;
```

Which gets me this:

[image]

I would like to order these so the most popular opening move is at the top, then the next popular, and so on, but I can't seem to get it. I seen that the process generated the column name `_c1`, and I tried `ORDER BY _C1`, but that didn't help.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `order by`. You can either repeat the aggregate function in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT opening_name, count(*)
FROM whiteopeningmove
GROUP BY opening_name
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Or better yet, assign an explicit alias, and reuse it in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT opening_name, count(*) as cnt
FROM whiteopeningmove
GROUP BY opening_name
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```